# How to correctly handle media.play() promise across browsers

Tags: javascript, firefox, promise, media-player, video.js

I am trying to play some audio using videojs. As autoplay is unreliable across browsers, there is a [blog post on the video js website](https://blog.videojs.com/autoplay-best-practices-with-video-js/) where they advice to do this:

```
let audioPlayer = videojs('audio-element');

audioPlayer.ready(function() {
           
   var promise = audioPlayer.play();

   if (promise !== undefined) {
       promise.then(function() {
           console.log('AUDIO: Autoplay started!');
       }).catch(function(error) {
           console.log('AUDIO: Autoplay was prevented.');
           // do something to let people start audio manually
       });
   }

});
```

This works perfectly in Chrome and Edge, but Firefox seems to never resolve the promise. Using debugger I can see its state pending though, but none of my console.logs are executed.

How can I get this to work in Firefox?

Answer (score -1):

I would instead do:

```
promise.then(function() {
// Autoplay started!
}, function(error) {
// Autoplay was prevented.
});
```

Comment: This is exactly the same code that quenn is using?